# ModX Revo - как добавить рекламу вниз каждой страницы pdoPage, если &ajaxMode=`scroll`?

Tags: modx, прокрутка, revo, pdoresource

Вывожу элементы на страницу так:

```
<div id="pdopage"> 
    [[!+page.nav]]
      <div class="rows"> [[!pdoPage?
        &parents=`15`
        &ajaxMode=`scroll`
        &limit=`6`
        &tpl=`ant.row`
        &includeTVs=`city,about,status,basic,index`
        &where=`[[!filter]]`
        &resources=`[[+sortedList]]`
        &sortby=`ids`
        ]]
    [[$Reklama]]
      </div>
    </div>
```

по 6 элементов, если пользователь скроллит страницу вниз, подгружаются следующие 6 штук и т.д.
Когда убираю скролл:

```
&ajaxMode=`scroll`
```

тогда [[$Reklama]] - просто div с картинкой - нормально подгружается на каждую страницу внизу. А вот как сделать, чтоб и скролл был и реклама выходила на каждую страницу - то есть через каждые 6 элементов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте параметр `&tplWrapper` это чанк-обёртка, для заворачивания всех результатов. Понимает один плейсхолдер: `[[+output]]`

```
&tplWrapper=`@CODE: [[+output]] [[$Reklama]]`
```

т.е. после вывода 6 ваших элементов он будет показывать рекламу

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: а как передать в сниппет номер страницы? вот так загадочные вещи творятся --- &tplWrapper=@CODE: [[+output]] [[!mobile?page=[[+page]]]]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/947863/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-switch-case-%d0%b2-php

Comment: отзовитесь, пожалуйста )