# Не работает switch case в PHP

Tags: php, modx, switch, revo, case

Параметр $page приходит нормально, ибо код

```
return $page;
exit;
```

без проблем выводит варианты 1, 2, 3, 4 и т.д.

А вот такой код

```
<?php
$output = '';
//return $page;
//exit;
switch ($page) {
    case '1':
        $output = $modx->getChunk('Mobile1');
        break;
    case "2":
        $output = $modx->getChunk('Mobile2');
        break;
    case 3:
        $output = $modx->getChunk('Mobile3');
        break;
    case 0:
        $output = $modx->getChunk('Mobile4');
        break;
}
return $output;
```

при любом варианте $page всегда срабатывает только на последнюю строчку, case 0.

В чём проблема? (это ModX Revo, подразумевается, что $page приходит в параметре $_GET)

Просмотрел эту "1" в hex редакторе. Получилась такая хрень:

```
<20><31><0D><0A><20><20><20><20><20><20><20><20>
```

пробел, 1, перенос строки и куча пробелов.

Теперь пытаюсь прикрутить

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $str);
```

вообще пустую строку выдаёт (

Comment: сдается мне.если убрать кавычки в `case `1`` то все заработает, или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызывать сниппет надо так:

```
&tplWrapper=`@CODE: [[+output]] {{!mobile?page=[[+page]]}}`
```

Ну и выбор тогда так:

```
<?php
$output = '';
switch ((int)$page) {
case 1:
    $output = $modx->getChunk('Mobile1');
    break;
case 2:
    $output = $modx->getChunk('Mobile2');
    break;
case 3:
    $output = $modx->getChunk('Mobile3');
    break;
case 0:
    $output = $modx->getChunk('Mobile4');
    break;
}
return $output;
```

Comment: Спасибо, Вы опять меня выручили, всё работает. Если не сложно, дайте ссылку на документацию по этому вопросу, я бы никогда не догадался, что нужно использовать фигурные скобки. Где это есть вообще?

Answer (score 0):

я бы на вашем месте сделал как-то так

```
$page = intval(trim($page));
$m = [4,1,2,3];    
// $m = $page < 4 : $page : 0;
// $m = $page % 4;
$output = $modx->getChunk("Mobile{$m[$page]}");
```

для демонстрации проблемы вашего кода, и небольших раздумий о приведении типов и сравнении строк:

```
$page = " 1\r\n    ";
switch($page){
   case '1' : echo "ooops!";    break;
   case "1" : echo 'oooooops!'; break;
   case  1  : echo 'wow!';      break;
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. проблема: $page = intval(trim($page)); опять всегда выводит 0, соответственно, всегда Mobile4. Мож там что-то другое на входе в $page? как поймать?

Comment: Вообще оно передаётся из pdoPage параметром

&tplWrapper=`@CODE: [[+output]] [[!mobile?page=[[+page]]]]`

Comment: @ВладимирМалахов вы в case своем от строк избавились?  что `var_dump($page)` говорит?

Comment: выводит так: string(9) "1"  string(9) "2"  string(9) "3" и т.д.

Comment: В итоге, была такая фигня (выяснил, отправив результат в текстовый файл): $page приходил как [[+page]] - вот вам и string(9). А отображался на странице как нормальные цифры, потому что вывод был (по мнению модекса) return [[+page]]. @Tunker помог разобраться. Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score -1):

```
$page = 2;
$output = '';
switch ($page) {
    case '1':
        $output = '$modx->getChunk(Mobile1)';
        break;
    case "2":
        $output = '$modx->getChunk(Mobile2)';
        break;
    case 3:
        $output = '$modx->getChunk(Mobile3)';
        break;
    case 0:
        $output = '$modx->getChunk(Mobile4)';
        break;
}
echo $output;
```

[у таракана уши не в ногах.](http://phpfaq.ru/humor/anecdotes#roach)